# Use jquery to change single variable that has multiple values

Tags: jquery, html, css

New to web programming - I am working with an open-source template, trying to change some text hover coloring.  I simply want to change border-color, but I am confused on how to change this variable as it has 3 values and applies to 3(?) different classes.  Template CSS code below:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus, .nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
     border-color: #e9ecef #e9ecef #ddd;
}
```

I can change "normal" variables with jquery:

```
$('.nav-link:hover').css("border-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)");
```

But I think there is something different with the supplied CSS syntax that I am not understanding.  How can I change the line of code above to successfully change border-color for .nav-link:hover?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you change this in CSS directly. Also, just FYI it's affecting the same element, just in 'focus' and 'hover' states. The three colours are the top, left/right, and bottom border colour, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery references DOM elements (HTML that becomes an element tree). CSS is not part of the DOM, it is styles that are applied to DOM elements. If you want to change the styling, you'll need to add to the css:

```
.nav-link:hover {
     border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Do this below the existing styles, and it will overwrite the styles above it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.nav-link:hover').css("border-color", "#e9ecef #e9ecef #ddd");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `border-color` [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color)

```
border-color: red cyan gold; is equivalent to

border-top-color: red;
border-right-color: cyan;
border-bottom-color: gold;
border-left-color: cyan;
```

In other words the formulation is `border-color: (top value) (left/right value) (bottom value)`

And has mentionned, you can change this simply in CSS, no need for jquery. You just need to make sure it is loaded after other rules, maybe in a different file all together (i.e. a `custom.css` that you require after loading the template's CSS). Something like:

```
.nav-link:hover {
     border-color: salmon salmon salmon;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I forgot to mention that I have a button that I want to use to be able to toggle a theme on/off, so I do want it to be dynamic.  You can see it here: https://keiferlewis.azurewebsites.net/.

There might be something else going on with the templated code, as Abido's suggestion above does not seem to work.  If you hit the crescent moon image, the text on the navbar loses its hover accents.  That's what I'm trying to change now.

Comment: Then I would suggest still doing it in CSS but toggling a class on a top element of your page, for instance the body. This way, you can have all of your rules in CSS when the body has a class `dark` for example

Answer (score 0):

However you can do that by CSS and jQuery as well. With jQuery you can try following way:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".nav-link", function(){
  $(this).css("border-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)");
})
$(document).on("mouseout", ".nav-link", function(){
  $(this).attr("style", "");
})
```

Also by CSS:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus, .nav-tabs .nav-link:hover {
     border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 }
```